# When connecting digital GND to chassis with a capacitor, what voltage rating should the capacitor have?

Tags: ground, emi-filtering

From testing the sensitivity of my device (USB communication) to EM noise, I figured out that if I use a capacitor to connect my digital GND to the chassis I can get rid of the noise (I think that's common mode noise) that goes in my PCB.

Given the following:

- My electronics are inside a metal chassis that also takes AC input.
- If my digital GND is left floating (no connection between GND/Earth), my digital GND gets capacitive/inductive coupled with the mains power. So if I measure the voltage between the Earth/Chassis and my digital GND I see ~60VAC. With the capacitors shorting GND/Earth this issue is also resolved.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiGAAV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Short GND earth]

Based on that, what voltage rating should my capacitors be? How can I know what voltage rating I need? (I did the shorting testing with 10V 22uF capacitors.)

Comment: Have you tried much smaller values of capacitor like 10 nF? Should be an easy test given you can measure the AC voltage.

Comment: I havent tried smaller Cap values. In fact I wonder how many Farads should my cap be for better immunity. So I will try that yes.

Comment: Can you try a high value resistor between digital gnd and chassis, like 1 Mohm?  Or would this violate an isolation requirement?

Comment: @SteveSh It doesn't violate any requirement, I will try that as well. Until now I have tried shorting with ferrite, 0 Ohms and capacitor. I will let you know when I try the 1Mohm and the lower value caps.

Comment: albeit remote, carefull as this might provide a path for static discharge to your PCB, if this is even an issue for your circuit ...

Comment: @citizen I know, I constantly think about that, I am also afraid that noise coming from the AC mains (The earth wire for example) can go to my PCB via these capacitors. My initial thought was to completely isolate the two, but this creates other issues :p Unfortunately I do not have the tools to perform EM testings as I would like to do (VNA, spectrum analyzers etc)

Comment: @Christianidis Vasileios. It may be that you have to plan ahead for several means, either a capacitor, or ferrite choke, or large resistor or a combination ... Have them all ready to be able to swap them in at a suitable laboratory (if you don't have the means) and then chose the best result ...

Comment: A more complete power/grounding diagram would be a big help.

Comment: @Christianidis Vasileios frankly I'd worry about the component voltage rating last as it is the least of your worries. This you can always adjust later when you have chosen the correct components and their values...

Comment: But you have external IO, what happens with the USB for example, you habe USB GND wire floating from the USB connector metal chassis?